# connecting two client socket

Tags: p2p

i have an application that has client and a server. The server is basically only used to store the file names that the clients have so that when other clients want to search for files, they can go the server, find the client that has the file they want and receive the file by directly connecting to it. By now, i can get the socket information of the client that has the file requested by the other client. However, i am now confused about how to connect these two clients. Do i have to create a separate client and a server socket between the two clients or there are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Now You have two choices:-

1. Let the server continue his role, and the server can act as an intermediary between the two parties. It should download the file from the client which has it and send it (via any suitable protocol) to the client who requested the file. This is called the Client -Server Architecture. This is a simple approach and you have the benefits such as file caching etc. i.e. If in future same file is requested the server can send it directly without asking for the client.
2. You can continue using the P2P architecture, and Create a separate a socket between the two parties, this is not straight forward and needs special care when multiple processes are working simultaneously.